# How to promise data-structures via Java Interfaces?

Tags: java, variables, data-structures, interface

Lets say I have an Interface "Car" and a concrete implementation of that Interface called "Campervan". I want every Car to have the following  variables:
 int seats
 int passengers

One might think the Interface could look like this:

```
interface Car{
  private Integer passengers;
  public Integer seats;
}
```

But this does not work for several reasons. The Java Interface does not allow variables other than FINAL and PUBLIC.

Since Java Interfaces do not allow variables other than public final ones, how can I realize the promise that all classes implementing the Interface (such as the Campervan) have an Internal Data-Structure including those variables? Public final variables are not always what I want my Interface to promise.

Note: I do understand the concept of Interfaces not including internal states and therefore forcing variables to be final. But does this mean Java Interfaces do not allow to make promises of internal data structure?

Comment: `how can I realize the promise that all classes implementing the Interface (such as the Campervan) have an Internal Data-Structure including those variables?` By not using an interface. Use a regular or abstract class and extend it. Each subclass will have the structures you define in the superclass.

Comment: I think a **contract** would be the better word rather than a **promise** (a promise is widely associated with an asynchronous programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of interfaces is to separate the abstraction from the implementation. By asking classes that implement the interface to follow some sort of implementation, you are defying the concept of the interface. You define the interface, so that you don't care how it is implemented, as long as the classes that implement it do what they promise to do (you should not be worried about how they do it).

In your example you can have this interface:

```
interface Car{
   public Integer getPassengers();
   public Integer getSeats();
}
```

Having the `Car` interface, you can call the `getPassengers()` method anytime you need it, without caring what the class (implementor of the interface) is doing to get you the number of passengers.

Answer (score 3):

The interface is intended for use by other parts of your program, and the internal data structure is for the implementation of the interface to decide. If you want to reuse some internal data structure in a class hierarchy you should use an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 - Use an abstract class instead:

```
public abstract class Car{
    private Integer passengers;
    private Integer seats;

    // setters and getters...
}
```

This of course will not work if your implementing classes already extends some other class:

Solution 2 - Add getters and setters to the interface:

```
interface Car{
    Integer getPassengers();
    Integer getSeats();

    void setPassengers(Integer value);
    void setSeats(Integer value);
}
```

In addition, you can't mark something as `private` in an interface. It just makes no sense. The purpose of an interface is making client code able to access members without knowing what object and what implementation it is using. Thus, private members are quite useless in interfaces because client code can't access it any way.